# Selecting a range of records from a file in Unix

Tags: unix

I have 4,930,728  records on a file text file in unix. This file is used to ingest images to Oracle web center content using batchloader. `<<EOD>>` indicate end of record as per below sample.

I have two questions

1. After processing 4,300,846 of 4,930,728 record(s), the batchloader fails for whatever resoan. Now I want to create a new file with records from 4,300,846 to 4,930,728. How do I do achieve that?
2. I want to split this text file containing 4930728 records into multiple files each contaiting range of (1,000,000) records e.g. file 1 contains records from 0 to 10,000,000. The second file contains records from 1,000,001 to 20,000,000 and so on. How do I achieve this?

filename: `load_images.txt`

```
Action = insert

DirectReleaseNewCheckinDoc=1

dUser=Biometric

dDocTitle=333_33336145454_RT.wsq

dDocType=Document

dDocAuthor=Biometric

dSecurityGroup=Biometric

dDocAccount=Biometric

xCUSTOMER_MSISDN=33333

xPIN_REF=64343439

doFileCopy=1

fParentGUID=2CBC11DF728D39AEF91734C58AE5E4A5

fApplication=framework

primaryFile=647229_234343145454_RT.wsq

primaryFile:path=/ecmmigration_new/3339_2347333145454_RT.wsq

xComments=Biometric Migration from table OWCWEWW_MIG_3007

<<EOD>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1:

```
head -n 4930728 myfile.txt | tail -n $(echo "4930728 - 4300846" | bc)
```

Answer #2 - to split the files in 1000 0000 lines:

```
split -l 10000000 myfile.txt ### It will create file like xaa,xab and so on
```

Comment: Answer # 2 works however,  answer # 1 does not work..head -n 4930728 /samba/migration/fi900007_load/LOAD.txt | tail -n $(echo "4930728 - 4300846" | bc)
usage: tail [+/-[n][lbc][f]] [file]
       tail [+/-[n][l][r|f]] [file]

Comment: Ideally it's working for me so should work for you (may be shell versions playing here). try head -n 4930728 /samba/migration/fi900007_load/LOAD.txt | tail -n 629882 and see if that works?

Comment: i tried .. but does not write anything to ouput file. I am using solaris sparc 10. head -n 4930728 /samba/migration/fi900007_load/LOAD.txt | tail -629882 > resubmit.txt